# Logging into a two different log file types in Codeigniter

Tags: logging, codeigniter

Is it possible in CI (natively) to log into two different files from two different controllers? I haven't found such option in user manual nor any solution in Google.

Is there any 3rd party logging library available for CI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for the same but couldn't find anything.  I tweaked the code and it works fine.
I have posted the same to CI forum http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-25933.html

Have a look it probably will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the Log library with your own log class, specially override `function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE)`. You can see the original Log library code in the file `system/libraries/Log.php`. To create your own Log library, overriding default behaviour, read [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Create the file `system/application/libraries/MY_Log.php`:

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log {

  function MY_Log()
  {
    parent::CI_Log();
  }
  //your code
  //...
  function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE)
  {
  //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in CI (natively) to log into two different files from two different controllers?

No, it isn't. Log file names are pretty much hard coded. See `system/libraries/Log.php`

> Is there any 3rd party logging library available for CI?

That I don't know, but assuming you come empty-handed from Google, I would either ask on the CodeIgniter forums, create your own logging library, or extend the existing one. [Instructions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are fine with changing core log file it can easy by following below 
goto main/core/log.php
and then replce

```
$filepath = $this->_log_path.'log-'.date('Y-m-d').'.'.$this->_file_ext;

$filepath = $this->_log_path.'log-'.date('Y-m-d').'.'.$this->_file_ext;
if($level == 'ERROR'){
    $filepath = $this->_log_path.'error-'.date('Y-m-d').'.'.$this->_file_ext;
}
```